# howto render only the visible items of a listview

Tags: android, listview

In my understanding a ListView only loads and renders the visible items, but in my case it seems, that it always renders all items. Because of that it take up to 5 seconds (for ~150 entries), until the ListView becomes visible.

Logcat shows:

```
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=4740ms;
```

If I do not load the images, it takes ~1 seconds. From my point of view also much to slow.

Limiting it to 5 entries, the list apears fast...

Here is simplyfied the code I'm using.

```
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
listView.setAdapter(new ContactAdapter(context, contacts));
```

---

```
ContactAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contactList = contacts;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_with_pic_ex, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imgPicture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

    holder.imgPicture.setImageBitmap(getPhotoAsBitmap(contact.getID()));
    holder.txtName.setText(contact.getName());
    holder.txtDate.setText(contact.getDate());
    
    return convertView;
}

private Bitmap getPhotoAsBitmap(final int ID) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, ID);
    InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), uri, true);

    Bitmap bitmap;
    if (is == null)
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.contour_dark);
    else {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

It takes quite the same time, whether I use hires or thumbnail pictures.

Could you please help me to make code faster.

Comment: I would suggest you use the newer `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.

Comment: The biggest problem here is that you didn't cache any of the variables. Limiting to 5 and putting a log inside of `getView()` to tell you how many times it is called is one way. Enabling and disabling the views using `position` as basis might help. But at end of the day, why not just using `RecyclerView`?

Comment: If the RecyclerView makes it running faster, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering is slow because of `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` this instruction is slow, you have to do processing in a background thread before render.

it can be something like this:

```java
private static class ContactLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Contact>> {
    
    private final Context context;
    
    public ContactLoader(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Contact> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        List<Contact> contacts = getContactListSomeWhere();
        for(Contact contact : contacts) {
            contact.setImageBitmap(getPhotoAsBitmap(contact.getID()))
        }
        return contacts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Contact> contacts) {
        super.onPostExecute(contacts);
        // Render data to ListView
    }

    private Bitmap getPhotoAsBitmap(final int ID) {
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, ID);
        InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), uri, true);

        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (is == null)
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.contour_dark);
        else {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand, how this should help. The doInBackground method loads the images serial, too. onPostExecution is called after doInBackground has finished. 
It also consumes a lot of memory, because all images are stored in the contacts list.
AsycTask is depricated for API 30+ by the way.
Could you please explain, how your solution should help.